# which information should be considered critical before attempting to save in a cookie?

Tags: asp.net, .net, cookies, browser

In my site I am using cookie based authentication system where I save the login credentials like username and password in a browser cookie. Is it a bad practice ? if so how this can be a threat to the security ?

Comment: Username can be seaved in a cookie, but password is a really bad idea

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a bad practice. You should never save sensitive information in a cookie. This information is accessible on the user's machine in plain text and could be altered and sent back to the application with bad data. You should always store this on the server, either in session variables, or permanently in a database.

Anything that is sensitive or critical for your application to function properly you should avoid. You may store things to make the user experience better, like layout, colors, last viewed pages, etc. You may also store the user name to provide a 'Remember Me' kind of login as long as you authenticate on submission via passwords.

Comment: so I should store nothing in cookies ?

Comment: You may also want to check this article about cookies, specially the security section http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx